# .current_page_ancestor broken in Twenty Eleven

Tags: theme-development, menus, css, theme-twenty-eleven

I would like to have a level 1 menu in a vertical menu and a full menu in a vertical menu in the left sidebar in Twenty Eleven. My problem is that I would like to make the top item bold if the user is in it, or in one of it's child menues.

The ideal solution would be to apply a rule for `.current_page_ancestor`. But for my biggest surprise, that rule IS already in the original css file for Twenty Eleven. But it seems to be broken, as nothing happens!

```
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Do you know how to fix this? Is there a ticket for this bug already?

To have an idea, have a look at this site, I made the selector red to make it visible. What I would like to achieve is that the top menu stays red even if I'm in one of the child menus on the left.

[sample page](http://kozossegikertek.brainhurt.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `.current-page-ancestor` selector to your style, note the use of hyphens instead of underscores.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. So did the developers of WP. I'll start a Ticket. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Im not sure, but there may be a reason theres a class that uses underscores and another that uses hyphens.

Comment: There is one now: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18756

Comment: For the reason, I found a ticket, it's actually for backwards compatibility. But the CSS should be modified.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it would be something like that. Which is the preferred selector now?

Comment: I think we need to use both, in this strange form. #access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current-page-ancestor > a {
 font-weight: bold;
}